# Dynamic lambda expression with dynamic parameter

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, lambda

Given this class

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This method (in some other class)...

```
private Func<Foo, string> Compile(string body)
{
    ParameterExpression prm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "foo");
    LambdaExpression exp = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { prm }, typeof(string), body);
    return (Func<Foo, string>)exp.Compile();
}
```

Will take the right hand side of a lambda expression and give me back a delegate. So if it is called like this:

```
Foo f = new Foo { Name = "Hamilton Academicals" };
//foo => foo.Name.Substring(0,3)
Func<Foo, string> fn = Compile("foo.Name.Substring(0,3)");
string sub = fn(f);
```

Then *sub* will have the value "Ham".

All well and good, however, I would like to make Foo subclass DynamicObject (so that I can implement TryGetMember to dynamically work out property values), so I want to take the expression and get the equivalent of this

```
Func<dynamic, dynamic> fn = foo => foo.Name.Substring(0,3);
```

I've tried `Expression.Dynamic` using a custom `CallSiteBinder`, but that fails with No property or field `Bar` exists in type `Object` (when I try to access `foo.Bar` dynamically). I'm assuming that is because the call to get `foo.Bar` needs to be dynamically dispatched (using `Expression.Dynamic`), but that isn't going to work for me because a key aim is that a user can enter a simple expression and have it executed. Is it possible?

Comment: For that I assume you need another parser which works specifically with dynamic expressions. This one is not going to work. Maybe just use full blown compiler (Roslyn)? How complex expressions are expected?

Comment: @Evk - Yep. After I posted I came to the same conclusion. Expressions will be simple (one liners). Can't use Roslyn as the generated assemblies aren't eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: You can load generated assemblies into separate app domains and tear them down. Of course that will hit perfomance and in general not very nice solution, but might be better than nothing, depending on your requirements to perfomance.

Comment: True... except I want to target .NET Core

Comment: Well, then you are out of luck I think, at least until they implement dll unloading in .NET Core (that's upcoming feature as far as I know). Implementing your own parser which works with dynamic expressions might be quite not trivial.

Comment: Old question, but just for interest ... How are the resulting Func<>s evaluated? - Could there be an option to replace the property accessor with a call to some static method that gets the property value at runtime? - You'd have to mutate the Expression before passing it to DynamicExpressionParser though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working, if it'll help you out:

**Compiler**:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
using System.Linq.Expressions;


namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    public class Compiler
    {
        public static Func<CustomDynamic, TResult> Compile<TResult>(string body)
        {
            ParameterExpression prm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(CustomDynamic), typeof(CustomDynamic).Name);
            LambdaExpression exp = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { prm }, typeof(TResult), body);
            return (Func<CustomDynamic, TResult>)exp.Compile();
        }
    }
}
```

**Dynamic Object**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    public class CustomDynamic
    {
        ExpandoObject _values;
        public CustomDynamic()
        {
            _values = new ExpandoObject();
        }

        public void AddProperty(string propertyName, object propertyValue)
        {
            var expandoDict = _values as IDictionary<string, object>;
            if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                expandoDict[propertyName] = propertyValue;
            else
                expandoDict.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
        }

        public string GetString(string propertyName)
        {
            var expandoDict = _values as IDictionary<string, object>;
            if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                return (string)expandoDict[propertyName];
            else
                throw new KeyNotFoundException($"dynamic object did not contain property {propertyName}");
        }
        public int GetInt(string propertyName)
        {
            var expandoDict = _values as IDictionary<string, object>;
            if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                return (int)expandoDict[propertyName];
            else
                throw new KeyNotFoundException($"dynamic object did not contain property {propertyName}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Use Case:**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CustomDynamic f = new CustomDynamic();
            f.AddProperty("Name", "Hamiltonian Physics");

            Func<CustomDynamic, string> fn = Compiler.Compile<string>("CustomDynamic.GetString(\"Name\").SubString(0, 3)");

            string sub = fn(f);

            Console.WriteLine(sub);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It just utilises the `ExpandoObject` class.  It's unfortunate that you'd need to go through its API to create objects, like "AddProperty" for every property, but heyho.

The `DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda` is a bit of a pain when it comes to generic methods as well, so I had to create type-specific accessors, which ***isn't the best, but it's working.***